# How can I add a field for featured image on backend of a custom Taxonomy?

Tags: theme-development, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I came accross this problem when trying to create a new wordpress Theme,
I want to add a custom term field for featured images on the backend of a custom taxonomy,

I have followed [this](https://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/) tutorial and managed to add the field, but this is just a plain text field.

Is there any source of code or any suggestions on how could I "code" myself a featured image field?

Comment: Quick and dirty: https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/

Comment: Hello @vancoder , thanks for the info, but the thing is I dont want to add a plugin, this has to be happening from the theme itself.

Comment: The Featured Image field is just a text field.  I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.